# Can asp.mvc 2 project work with office 365

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, office365-apps

I have asp.net mvc 2 project. now there is a requirement where I need to store documents in Office 365 and allow it to access office 365 in windows tab or windows phone? Is it possible write those documents from asp.net mvc 2 project or should I write separate new application to use office 365 apis?

Please guide. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried? Technically, it shouldn't matter as the 365 APIs are a separate piece of functionality, *but* if they depend on a newer version of .NET than you're running, which is very likely, you might have to upgrade that, which may or may not require some updates to your existing codebase. Your safest bet is probably starting a new application, but with stuff like this, just *try it* and see what happens. If it works, great. If not, well, now you know.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I am very new to this area. I'm not sure where to start. just wondering whether should I have to create completely new project in VS2013 (using those templates given for Office365) or can I make it work on the asp.net mvc 2 as a module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes it can". The Office 365 api is no different to any other REST API and you can call it from anything that understands HTTP.

In current versions of ASP.NET you would use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this but I am pretty sure that was introduced in a later .net version than the one MVC2 was in.

I think for MVC2 you can use [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the same thing. In any case, the way you would call any REST API in MVC2 is the way you'd call the Office 365 API